# reorder List starting at given position

Tags: c#, list

List:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>(){ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

let's say we want to reorder it. The beginning should be at number "2"

```
// 2,3,4,5,6,0,1
```

or at number 5

```
// 5,6,0,1,2,3,4
```

**how do you do it with C#?**

the reason: Imagine that you have an index of a given number in the List (number 3, index 3). You want to get the second number from the right - it'll be 5.

Unfortunately, if the starting number is **at the end of the List** (numbers 5 and 6) - out of range exception will be thrown, **because there's no 7 and 8!**

The idea is to reorder the List!

- We enter Nr. 5 - we get 0 (5,6,0).
- We enter Nr. 6 - we get 1 (6,0,1), etc.

or maybe there is some other (read - better) way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reorder the list. You could get the number with the following function:

```
int GetNumber(List<int> list, int fromValue, int index) 
{
    return list[(list.IndexOf(fromValue) + index) % list.Count()];
}
```

You could call the function like this:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>(new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
int number = GetNumber(list1, 5, 2); // number = 0
```

Comment: Are you sure the `- 1` is necessary?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: I added the `-1` to match the OP's expected behavior (index of 3 = two at the right).

Comment: But I'll remove the -1 anyway it's more logical ;-)

Answer (score 5):

A little Linq can do this pretty easily:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>(new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });

var numToStart = 4;

//reorderedList will be {4,5,6,0,1,2,3}
var reorderedList = list1.Skip(numToStart).Concat(list1.Take(numToStart));
```

Comment: This should work, but it's re-creating the entire list rather than just moving the items in place, or for that matter the solutions provided by the others that don't involve any list mutation.

Comment: No it isn't; it's iterating through the list in a particular way defined by the methods. Skip() and Take() do not require creating new collections internally, like OrderBy() and GroupBy() do; they simply enumerate their source collection with the twist implied by the name (like not yielding the first X items, or yielding ONLY the first X items). Now, if you needed to actually persist the reordered items then yes this wouldn't be in-place, but that doesn't seem to be a requirement, and an in-place solution would be more complex.

Comment: The OP's reqs would involve storing the results of the query as a list.  If you didn't, and just perform this query each time then you turn a O(1) list lookup into a O(n) lookup, so it's still a substantially inferior solution.

Comment: @KeithS this solution worked great! but I'll be sticking with other method for now, because it's doesn't require list creation. anyway, thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 4):

The better way to do it is to use the mod operator %. This gives you the remainder when you divide an int by another int. The way this works is something like this:

```
int nextIndex = (currentIndex + offset) % length;
```

So, if your current index is 5, your offset is 2 and your length is 6 then:

```
5 + 2 = 7
7 / 6 = 1 remainder 1 (or 7 mod 6 = 1)
therefore nextIndex = 1
```